# What are the differences between the US and UK versions of the Harry Potter audio books?

Tags: harry-potter, audio-book

I'm trying to decide between Jim Dale (US) and Stephen Fry (UK) audio book version.

What, if any, are the differences between the two versions of the audio books? How well were they received?

English is not my first language if it makes any difference.

Comment: You can read about some of the differences at http://mindtherant.blogspot.com/2012/04/harry-potter-jim-dale-stephen-fry.html.

Comment: Aside from the two different narrators, music, and text? ;)
IIRC - Jim Dale makes an effort to 'perform' different voices whereas Fry is doing a more straight reading of the text with less variance between the characters. If you enjoy hearing a 60+ yr old man attempt to voice a 12 yr old girl then Jim Dale is the way to go.

Comment: Jim Dale does this very very well, just by the way.

Comment: For someone who isn't English, is Stephen Fry's accent going to be more difficult to listen to?

Comment: @System If you can understand English/Scottish/Irish accents of actors in the movies without subtitles, I suppose you would be alright.

Comment: "English is not my first language if it makes any difference." Did you learn British English or American English? If you're from the continent, the British version will be easier for you to understand. If not, likely the American version.

Comment: Stephen Fry's accent is very easy to comprehend, at least to me – I'm German, quite used to British English, but there are many speakers of both AE and BE I don't understand nearly as well as Stephen Fry. Besides, the name Fry an absolute superlative in terms of [nerdy-British-humour awesomeness](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ij1pZvv9m0g), in case you're into that... (don't worry if you don't understand _that video_, he's deliberately brabbling pretentious nonsense there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are really easy to understand even for a foreigner as myself. Both readers are comedian with a very good pronunciation.

I prefer the Jim Dale version because of the various voices he is performing.
Hagrid is a very convincing half-giant and I'm loving McGonagal scottish's accent. And the sorting-hat's songs...

I found as well to my great surprise that the text read by J. Dale is much more extensive than the one read by S. Fry. It even includes some text not present in the French translation for instance.

Steven Fry is better at using inflection in order to outline part of the text. This is sometime very pleasant and really missing from Dale's version.

The last point is that J Dale is reading faster than S Fry. To me it looks like a "plus" as I am finding audiobook way to slow. (Especially as compared to my reading speed which is easily 4 time faster.)

Hope it will help you find the version you will like the most.

Comment: thanks! I ended up alternating between the two before settling with Fry in the end! I agree with your comments on both versions, I somehow found Dale a bit tiring...

Comment: I like Stephen Fry's performance of the Sherlock Holmes series quite a bit, but for Potter, I prefer Dale's version. I've listened to both versions of Potter at least twice each (actually, twice for Fry, and like 15 times for Dale!)

Answer (score 1):

- UK uses the British version of the book, and pronounces words in the British pronunciation (ie 'lieutenant' as 'left-ten-ant')
- US uses the US (Scholastic) version of the book, using American pronunciation (ie 'lieutenant' as 'loo-ten-ent'), despite using a British accent